# How to find string in text file with Windows command and copy next 5 characters

Tags: windows, string, batch-file, cmd, pattern-matching

I have input.txt:

```
asdfasfasdfa,abc12345,abc98591,abc13456,abc95934,abc53455  
safasdfasdfa,abc31212,abc55455,abc23124,abc54834,abc13689  
...
```

I need output.txt:

```
12345  
98591  
13456  
95934  
53455  
31212  
55455  
23124  
54834  
13689
```

so I need find all "abc" string and copy next 5 charcters (after "abc") to new file and each number must be in new line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check it out:

```
@echo OFF &SETLOCAL
FOR %%f IN (*.txt) DO (
    ECHO Processing %%f --^> %%~nf.txt.new
    (for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("%%~f") do call:doit "%%a")>"%%~nf.txt.new"
)
GOTO :EOF

:doit
SET "line=%~1"
SET "first=true"
:loop
SET "token="
FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=," %%b IN ("%line%") DO (
    SET "token=%%b"
    SET "line=%%c"
)
SET "out=%token:~-5%"
IF NOT DEFINED first ECHO(%out%
SET "first="
IF DEFINED line GOTO :loop
GOTO :EOF
```

Comment: It dosen't work. In output I have: "PATH>(for /f "delims=abc" %b in ("abc12345") do echo(%b )"

Comment: How to use this do all files in folder with output file name orginal_name+"_abc".txt ?

Comment: @user2567103  Please replace `file` with your file name. (in the line `(for /f "delims=" %%a in (file) do call:doit "%%a")>output.txt`). Please let me know, if you want to process entire folders.

Comment: Yest it works fine with replacing file name, but I'm wondering if it could work for each file *.txt in direct folder with specific output file name.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Working great!